Getting password ssh prompt after broken connection
I have the pubkey installed on the server I want to connect, and it works like a charm most of the times.
However, every time I close my computer without first closing the connection, once I try to connect back to the server, it asks me for the SSH user password.
I tried to look at other similar questions, but none of the ones I've found seem to have this specific pattern...

Here are the output when it's asking for the password:
> ssh -vv acquario3_alberto 
OpenSSH_9.3p2, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/username/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/username/.ssh/config line 24: Applying options for acquario3_alberto
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -W acquario3:22 dei
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.3
user@domain's password: 

If I then proceed to put the password in, logout, and run the same command, I get:
> ssh -vv acquario3_alberto
OpenSSH_9.3p2, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/username/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/username/.ssh/config line 24: Applying options for acquario3_alberto
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -W acquario3:22 dei
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to acquario3:22 as 'remote_username'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:RhqUOGGi/9i3mG6pRkD1yUpcC5x5SUoaLPL4tFOgeSs
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'acquario3' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:30
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:E9SOetz/CmM/7B8kUzukfZtvNxzunRpfKB/NqWxDT+4
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:E9SOetz/CmM/7B8kUzukfZtvNxzunRpfKB/NqWxDT+4
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:E9SOetz/CmM/7B8kUzukfZtvNxzunRpfKB/NqWxDT+4
Authenticated to acquario3 (via proxy) using "publickey".
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:8989 forwarded to remote address 127.0.0.1:8989
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 8989.
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new port-listener [port listener] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8989.
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new port-listener [port listener] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:8989 forwarded to local address localhost:8989
debug1: channel 2: new session [client-session] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug2: channel 2: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts for acquario3 / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts2 for acquario3 / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug1: Remote: /home/remote_username/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/remote_username/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 8989, connect localhost:8989
debug2: forwarding_success: -1 expected forwarding replies remaining
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 2
debug2: channel 2: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 2: setting env LANG = "it_IT.UTF-8"
debug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 2: request shell confirm 1
debug1: pledge: network
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 2: callback done
debug2: channel 2: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 2
debug2: channel 2: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 2
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.5.0-26-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

111 updates can be applied immediately.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

15 additional security updates can be applied with ESM Apps.
Learn more about enabling ESM Apps service at https://ubuntu.com/esm


1 updates could not be installed automatically. For more details,
see /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log
Last login: Fri Apr  5 10:34:28 2024 from 147.162.2.98
> (base) remote_username@acquario3:~$ 

This is my .ssh/config profile for this connection:
Host acquario3_alberto
  HostName acquario3
  Port 22
  User remote_username
  LocalForward 8989 127.0.0.1:8989
  RemoteForward 8989 localhost:8989
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p dei

where dei is another connection with the following setting:
Host dei
  HostName login.something.it
  Port 22
  User another_remote_username

And my pubkey is installed in both servers, and also the two server have a pubkey installed between them (thus except when the connection breaks, it works fine)

Please [edit] and post the output of ssh -vv …; one from when it works fine, another one from when the problem occurs.

Are you sure the password prompt is from ssh, rather than a screen locker? On your system or the remote system?

@KamilMaciorowski posted

@waltinator idk, if it was a screen locker, it would never let me access it with the ssh pubkey

"every time I close my computer" – By "close", do you mean "shutdown the OS"? Or what?

@KamilMaciorowski put in stan by long enough to timeout the ssh connection

Does it really print user@domain's password:? I mean there is remote_username@acquario3_alberto (at some stage remote_username@acquario3) and another_remote_username@dei (at some stage another_remote_username@login.something.it), and no clear reason for anything else; so I wonder: where do user and domain come from?

@KamilMaciorowski ahah sorry, I replaced my actual username in different times, using different replacement, I'll update the logs asap and ping you when I eventually do it
